# Получить все записи из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

у меня есть 3 таблицы. 1 кампании отсюда берется только id, 2 цвета где 2 поля id и hex, и таблица связи с полями campaign_id, color_id и order для сортировки. Я прописал связь следующим образом

```
public function getColor(): \yii\db\ActiveQuery
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Color::class, ['id' => 'color_id'])
            ->viaTable('campaign_color', ['campaign_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

мне нужно извлечь все цвета всех компаний одного пользователя, я так понимаю мне нужно сначала получить все color_id в связанной таблице и все campaign_id юзера и взять только те цвета которые есть у этих кампаний. я пытался сделать это через leftJoin('color') но конструкция получилась излишне громоздкой и несла много не нужных атрибутов, подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: В направлении left join :) могу привести пример запроса на чистом SQL если будет описание(нормальное) того что нужно выбрать и структура таблиц и связей :)

Comment: я смог получить при помощи innerJoin id всех цветов у всех компаний `$campaignColors  = self::find()
            ->select(['color_id', 'campaign_id'])
            ->innerJoin('advert_campaign c', 'c.user_id = ' . $userId)
            ->all();` теперь мне надо как то достать сами цвета в формате hex из таблицы color, вот это не получается.

Comment: *мне надо как то достать сами цвета в формате hex из таблицы color* Ну так нужен ещё один innerJoin - на сей раз таблицы color. Между первым innerJoin и финальным all(). Ну и соответственно поправить select.